# Append to a file in FTP

Tags: java, ftp

I need to append data to an existing CSV file. The CSV file is present on a FTP server. We have a class called `FileWriter` which is helping us append data to a CSV file which is in local system but not in the file in FTP server. How can I append data to a CSV file on the remote FTP server?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do that would be to use a FTP Client, like the one in [Commons Net](http://commons.apache.org/net/). A useful method to use would then be `appendFileStream` in the class [FTPClient](http://commons.apache.org/net/api-3.2/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html).